# How to separate the number from string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string which consists of both char and integer .For example,

```
Business Call Numbers:
US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924
UK Toll Free 08081234567
India Toll Free 180012345678
Chennai Number 044222
Bangalore Number 0802214434
Conference Bridge 4542316572
```

Now i want to get the numbers after toll free and store it in a array and the other numbers in the another array.**I well known that it can be easily done** but,i did not know which method to use?Regular expression(indexof(),contains(),matches(),etc).

Can any one share your experience ?

Answer (score 1):

according to your inputs

try to use `lastIndexOf(" ");` method in inputs.

it returns your location of last space which all you need.

and then you can get next string which is your phone no.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924";

    int pos = str1.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String s[] = str1.subString(pos); //kind of
    //your s[1] is what you need 
}
}
```

Comment: Could you give any example ?

Comment: what is subString here?

Comment: check out java documents. you will get your ans

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924  UK Toll Free 08081234567  India Toll Free 180012345678 ";
        String numPattern = "\\d[-\\d]*\\d";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(numPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

---

For number after toll free

```
 String str1 = "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924  UK Toll Free 111  UK Toll sime 222 India Toll Free 333 ";
        String numPattern = "(toll free )\\d[-\\d]*\\d";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(numPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1.toLowerCase());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group().replace("toll free ", ""));
        }
```

Comment: question says :' i want to get the numbers after toll free'

Comment: If number like `UK Toll Free 08081234567 ABC` than it will also inclue ABC

Comment: Working good but all my number will be in a single string.How can proceed ?

Comment: No it should not include the ABC .I want the number after toll free is it possible? Masud

Comment: have modified for single string. Hope this helps

Comment: Ya working fine.Is it getting the number after toll free or just getting the number after char?

Comment: I want to get the number after only  toll free is it possible?

Comment: yes its possible. you need to get some basics of regex. :) you should modify numPattern as per your requirement. Try String numPattern = "(Toll Free )\\d[-\\d]*\\d"; Watch out for lower/upper case. have appended new code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern/Matcher as shown by Pranalee, but use this regex "[0-9-]+".

Comment: could you explain brief

Answer (score 0):

Using the example numbers, it looks like the numbers will not have spaces in them and also be at the end of a line, so you could use .split(" ") , which will use a space as your delimiter.

```
String a = "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924";
String[] b = a.split(" ");
String number = b[b.length-1];
if(b.length>2){
    String sToCheck = b[b.length-3] + " " + b[b.length-2];
    if(sToCheck.equals("Toll Free")){
        //Add to the toll free array
    }
}else{
    //Add to the non toll free array
}
```

Comment: how you will get the number if it is "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924 US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924"?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "US Toll Free 1-009-123-8924 ABC";
        String str2 = "UK Toll Free 08081234567 ABC";
        String str3 = "India Toll Free 180012345678";
        String str4 = "India Toll Free 180012345678";

        if(str1.contains("Toll Free") || str1.contains("store") ){
           //Store it one array
        }
        else{
          //Use other array.
        }   
        System.out.println(getMatch(str1));
        System.out.println(getMatch(str2));
        System.out.println(getMatch(str3));
        System.out.println(getMatch(str4));

    }

    private static String getMatch(String input) {
       return input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z ]+","");
    }
```